# Error : HTTPFault string: Unauthorized + sharepoint web service

Tags: php, sharepoint, wsdl, sharepoint-2007

I have sharepoint installed in my local windows server available through LAN. Now i am running a web-service in php on my local apache server like this:

```
<?php

//Authentication details
$authParams = array('login' => 'username', 'password' => 'password'); \

$listName = "TestList1";
$rowLimit = '150';
$wsdl = "http://www.blah.com/sharepoint/ListsWSDL.wsdl";

//Creating the SOAP client and initializing the GetListItems method parameters
$soapClient = new SoapClient($wsdl, $authParams);
$params = array('listName' => $listName, 'rowLimit' => $rowLimit);

//Calling the GetListItems Web Service
$rawXMLresponse = null;
try{
    $rawXMLresponse = $soapClient->GetListItems($params)->GetListItemsResult->any;
}
catch(SoapFault $fault){
    echo 'Fault code: '.$fault->faultcode;
    echo 'Fault string: '.$fault->faultstring;
}
echo '<pre>' . $rawXMLresponse . '</pre>';

//Loading the XML result into parsable DOM elements
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML($rawXMLresponse);
$results = $dom->getElementsByTagNameNS("#RowsetSchema", "*");

//Fetching the elements values. Specify more attributes as necessary
foreach($results as $result){
    echo $result->getAttribute("ows_LinkTitle")."<br/>";
}
unset($soapClient);
?>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

But control is going to catch block with error displayed as:

```
Fault code: HTTPFault string: Unauthorized
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Have you enabled the basic authentication in IIS ?

Comment: First check the WSDL file, the server location is in the wsdl file, right at the bottom. Please make sure this server location is correct.  

Please activate "Basic authentication" (in IIS6) for this sharepoint site you are trying to access.

Answer (score 0):

First check the WSDL file, the server location is in the wsdl file, right at the bottom. Please make sure this server location is correct.

Please activate "Basic authentication" (in IIS6) for this sharepoint site you are trying to access.

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled the basic authentication in IIS ?

Look at this link :
http://blogs.iis.net/nitashav/archive/2010/02/22/iis6-0-ui-vs-iis7-x-ui-series-basic-authentication.aspx

Check your credentials.

Try to change IIS Authentication Settings to Kerberos.

Comment: I have enabled Basic authentication in IIS 7 and restarted it. But still i am getting same error. I generated wsdl file also again.

Comment: @metalfight : Why basich authentication is needed? Or would https not work ? Im having the same problem with the Unauthorized error, and don't know how to proceed...